# Getting conversion error while using solve function on an expression generated using for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, type-conversion, equation

I am trying to find the first term 'p' of a geometric series with common ratio 1.05 in MATLAB as follows. However the solve function is giving the error as below (posted right after the code). I can't seem to figure out the reason for this error, because when I display the expression for 'sum', it is correctly showing an expression in terms of'p', but the problem arises when I try to equate that to a value, and solve for 'p'. Any insights would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
clear all;
clc;
t=20; %no. of terms in geometric series
sum =0;
jackpot = 1000; %sum of geometric series
%p is first term
syms p
for x=1:t
sum = sum + p*((1.05)^(x-1));
end
disp(sum);
eqn1 = sum == jackpot;
solve(eqn1,p);
```

Output:

```
(18614477322052275759*p)/562949953421312000

??? Error using ==> char
Conversion to char from logical is not possible.

Error in ==> solve>getEqns at 169
vc = char(v);

Error in ==> solve at 67
[eqns,vars] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Error in ==> geometric_trial at 13
solve(eqn1,p);
```

Comment: the issue is definitely here `eqn1 = sum == jackpot;`, what is the equation you want to solve?

Comment: @Marouen I want to solve the generated expression (18614477322052275759*p)/562949953421312000 = jackpot. So that becomes (18614477322052275759*p)/562949953421312000 = 94000000

Comment: in which part of the code was the expression generated?

Comment: @Marouen Umm, are you familiar with the MATLAB code ? In the output I've posted, can you see the output expression, before the errors show up ? So that means, the output is generated at the end of the for loop.

Comment: print `eqn1`. possibly try `eqn1 = ['sum =' eval(jackpot)];`

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the answer for this from a user Walter Roberson on another forum. Posting here, from his answer.

I was trying this on a version of MATLAB which is really old i.e. R2010a. In this, using 'symbolic_expression == symbolic_expression' does not set up an equation for later solving, but instead compares the two expressions for literal equality and returns a logical value immediately.

In versions that old, the easiest fix is to change

eqn1 = sum == jackpot

to

eqn1 = (sum) - (jackpot)
and let solve() deal with the implicit equality to 0.